# How to select external crystal in atmega162

Tags: avr, atmel, crystal, clock-speed

How to set AVR to select external crystal for clock?

A _delay_ms(1000) is producing a quick beep however it should produce 1 sec beep if it is operating on 12Mhz.

Could it be done programatically of it needs to be set using fuses?

I am using 33pf capacitor on crystal.

[image]

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2513-8-bit-AVR-Microntroller-ATmega162_Datasheet.pdf - page 36 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got these on atmega162 datasheet , it helped me and i got solution
[image]
[image]